# Eigenvalues of linear transformation $f(a_n)=a_{n+1}-a_n$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

The linear transformation $f:\mathbb{R^N}\to \mathbb{R^N}$ with $\mathbb{R^N}$ being the $\mathbb{R}$-Vectorspace of all sequences $(a_n)_{n\ge1}$ is defined as

$$f \big( (a_n)_{n \ge 1} \big) = ( a_{n+1}-a_n ) _{n \ge 1}$$

I am supposed to find all Eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $f$.
So I know that $f(a)=\lambda a$
and that means that 
$$\begin{align}a_{n+1}-a_n&=\lambda a_n \\
a_{n+1}&=(\lambda +1) a_n\end{align}$$

But now I'm lost... I don't really know what to do from here on...

Comment: It's not clear to me what the definition of $f $ is. $f $ is supposed to send elements of $R^N $ to elements of $R^N $.

Comment: is $(a_n)$ a sequence? Moreover, is $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ or not?

Comment: Yes, $(a_n)$ is a sequence and and $a \in \mathbb{R}$

@Simon It sends a sequence like $(a_1, a_2, a_3...)$ to $(a_2-a_1, a_3-a_2...)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost done. For any $\lambda$ consider the vector space of dimension one defined by

$$E_{\lambda}=\{\left(a_n=(\lambda+1)^{n+1}a_0\right)_n, a_0\in\Bbb{R}\}$$

Any sequence in this subspace is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\lambda$. So the linear transformation has any real as an eigenvalue with one dimensional (a line) eigenspace